# Bit confused about how to set up snapper BTRFS snapshots

Tags: btrfs, void-linux, snapper

I have installed void Linux created subvolumes redirected the root reinstalled grub and I am booting up fine.

Here's my /etc/fstab :

```
UUID=D7C4-586F                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults 0 2
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /              btrfs   subvol=/@,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /root          btrfs   subvol=/@root,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /var/cache     btrfs   subvol=/@cache,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /var/log       btrfs   subvol=/@log,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /var/tmp       btrfs   subvol=/@tmp,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=8b0e6c9e-3bcb-48b5-b014-94be842e8b53 /home          btrfs   subvol=/@home,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 0

UUID=15097b82-144a-4534-b9c5-e12bc550478b none           swap    sw 0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

I have installed Void into a single partition.

Now I don't know how to create snapper configs for @ and @home subvolumes separately

> Before creating a snapper configuration for a Btrfs subvolume, the
> subvolume must already exist. If it does not, you should create it
> before generating a snapper configuration.
>
> To create a new snapper configuration named config for the Btrfs
> subvolume at /path/to/subvolume, run:
>
> `snapper -c config create-config /path/to/subvolume`

But what would be the path to the subvolume '@' & ' @home ' in my case?

How can I install snapper-GUI in Void Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Before creating a snapper configuration for a Btrfs subvolume, the subvolume must already exist. If it does not, you should create it before generating a snapper configuration.

To create a new snapper configuration named *config* for the Btrfs subvolume at /path/to/subvolume, run:

```
sudo snapper -c config create-config /path/to/subvolume
```

you just have to replace */path/to/subvolume* with the **subvolume's mount point**

**To install snapper-GUI in Void Linux:**

https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/pv4ggd/how_can_i_install_snapper_gui_in_void_linux/

Comment: Since you've found a solution for your issue, please feel free to [accept the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This'll mark it as containing a solution and lift it out of the Unanswered -queue. You'll need to wait a while before accepting it tho, site rules.